# Use vars.get instead of '$' in Jmeter http request

Tags: http, groovy, jmeter

I have a question about using http request in Jmeter
I created a json request. and I tried to pass parameters that I used in previous steps (I saved it using vars.put("Expected_Offer_Name").
I would like to use vars.get("Expected_Offer_Name"), as parameter, but Jmeter refuse to use this parameter.

But when I use "${Expected_Offer_Name}" it worked OK.
1. what is the difference? in both cases I Want to pass a string parameter.
2. Is their a way to use vars,get instead.

[[image: Not working]][Not working]

[[image]][Working]

Is their a way to use vars.get in the json's http request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use vars in HTTP Request.

`vars` is a special variable only for scripting which is available only in:

1. [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) scripts

> Before invoking the script, some variables are set up. Note that these are JSR223 variables - i.e. they can be used directly in the script.

2. Beanshell/groovy Elements or functions.

It's also added for getting variables using the [right way](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223):

> ensure the script does not use any variable using ${varName} as caching would take only first value of ${varName}. Instead use :
>   vars.get("varName")

In other locations you need to get variable using `${varName}`

Comment: sorry but I am still not understand, I want to use vars,get("expected_offer_name") In the http request.  But Jmeter not allowed, so I use "${Expected_Offer_Name}".   You mentioned that this is not good since it will be cached, So what is the solution?  what to write instead of "${Expected_Offer_Name}"  in the json http request?

Comment: @Bastian You can't use `vars` in HTTP Request. So you should use`${Expected_Offer_Name}`. If your question is about inside JSR Sampler, the answer is different

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `vars.get("Expected_Offer_Name")` into [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get("Expected_Offer_Name"),)}
```

[image: JMeter Groovy Function]

You can use JMeter Functions anywhere in your Test Plan.

NB: you need [JMeter version at least 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31) in order to use `__groovy` function